# Get the url of aggregated CSS and JS

Tags: 8

I am looking to programmatically get the aggregated url that I can use to pre-load on a different page. Is there a method I can use in Drupal 8 to do this?

this url usually looks like:

`/sites/mytheme/files/css/css_On6fV7UTH_kMXvRAnOzTBfjow6RM77BJcrP4tbb-KoQ.css?t0uY2i`

Comment: Something like "the" aggregated asset URL does not exist. The generated assets are depending the module libraries and will vary page by page

Comment: How about getting the aggregated url for a node (another page)

Comment: I don't have an answer on this, you might get some information if you google about "Drupal placeholder token" or look for the same term on this site. But what you are trying to do is conceptionally prone to errors, as modules can declare assets to be loaded either in header or footer, or even later on a separate Ajax call.

Comment: I have never tried this before, but I think you can do this by using the advagg module together with brotli, to create a static file to use for pre-loading.